# How to rip LVL from .d2s Diablo II save

Tags: java, save

I have totally no idea where could I asked question like this.

I am wondering how to rip character LVL from D2 save, what pattern / which bit?? maybe someone have some clue? I need to do it in java

Comment: I remember changing the level with a hex editor some 10 years ago, perhaps google will help with that. The information should still be out there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

```
public static void ripD2sLvl(File source) throws IOException {
// rip character level from .d2s diablo II save
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(source);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
        is.skip(43);
        if ((is.read(new byte[1])) > 0) {
            System.out.println("=====reading from "+source.getName()+"======");
            //System.out.write(buffer);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buffer));
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

you can modify this function to return (int) lvl = buffer[0];